# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.google.android.gms.R$string.location_client_powered_by_google

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I get `NoSuchFieldError` whenever I run my project. Here is part of my my logcat

```
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.google.android.gms.R$string.location_client_powered_by_google
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ib.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hi.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404):    at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404):    at tabFragments.StartTab.onCreate(StartTab.java:87)
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1455)
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.detachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1258)
05-27 11:47:14.609: E/AndroidRuntime(13404):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:667)
```

I didn't find the same problem elsewhere but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412209/android-google-maps-api-v2-nosuchfielderror) problem looked similar. So I reinstalled my google services, cleaned and rebuild. Yet the problem persists.

Note: This problem started after updating google play services from SDK manager.

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check **location_client_powered_by_google** this name string to your google play services String file if not present then make it with same name in it.. thats it...

add this line:

```
<string name="location_client_powered_by_google">Powered by Google</string>
```